# How to debug Error Messsage in Odoo

Tags: error-handling, report, odoo-8

I have created my Own custom report in which when I print my report at that time the below error message will be created

```
500: Internal Server Error
```

I don't know where I should start with the problem solution. The log file in /var/log/odoo/ says:
and my log file `/var/log/odoo/`

```
"MissingError: ('MissingError', u'One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing.')"
```

Do you have any solution to resolve this problem ?.

Answer (score 0):

Try Running odoo.py when such error occur. It will show where exactly the error occurred. After you fix all the issues under odoo.py. You are good to go.